# Antivirus detects python.exe as idp.generic?

Tags: python

I am starting to learn python. Installed python 2.7 and Pycharm. When I opened the python console in Pycharm, my antivirus warned me that python.exe in path `venv\Scripts` was infected by `IDP.Generic` . Has anyone experienced this problem before? Is this a false positive case? I'm worried if it is really a malware in my pc...

Comment: https://support.avg.com/answers?id=906b0000000DwSTAA0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IDP generic means

> the detection was detected by a Identity Protection detection
>   component and it is a generalized file that got detected.

Practically means that the program behaved in a way that is close to what a malware does. This could be a false positive. I suggest doing the following :

1. update the signatures since a false alarm could be raised due to an outdated database.
2. Submit your python.exe to https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload to see what it does report.

In my opinion, it is a false positive.

Hope it helps

Comment: Virustotal says it's clean. That means this is false positive. It is really strange. I'm using avast and it is up to date. How could this happen?

Comment: I don't know why Avast thinks Python is a malware, but i have seen a lot of false positives with valid programs, games or other antivirus engines. It is not easy to create a generic signature to capture malware behavior. I found a recent comparative study about false alarms at https://www.av-comparatives.org/tests/false-alarm-test-march-2018/. Avast appears to have a good rating though.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing which Anti-Virus program you use... see [this link](https://support.avg.com/answers?id=906b0000000DekoAAC).

> We request you to disable AVG Protection temporarily by following the instructions as mentioned in this article: http://avgread.me/1GnMD3N and then reinstall the Python application. 
>   Once done with that please enable AVG Protection and add the installed path of Python application to AVG's exception.

Python is no malware, however, I also don't know where you downloaded your python distribution. Feel free to download it from the [official repositories for windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).