# IDP.Generic when i try to run a dll injector in visual studio. Is this safe to run? (can i even get a virus from VS?)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

DWORD GetProcId(const char* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

int main()
{
    const char* dllPath = "C:\\Users\\tme\\Downloads\\dll.dll";
    const char* procName = "Application.exe";
    DWORD procId = 0;

    while (!procId)
    {
        procId = GetProcId(procName);
        Sleep(30);
    }

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, procId);

    if (hProc && hProc != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        void* loc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

        WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0);

        HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, loc, 0, 0);

        if (hThread)
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    }

    if (hProc)
    {
        CloseHandle(hProc);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside from inadequate error handling, there is no virus in this code. Your anti-virus is likely just being too sensitive. There are legitimate reasons to inject a DLL into another process. Did you check to make sure the DLL itself is virus-free?

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/318294fb1792b49db6b676c4bfae3b2d516aa5649ed4214ed206e6e91f07c2b7/detection                                                                                  This is the DLL file that I would inject.

Comment: Also potentially this dll which was made in Visual Studio but shows up to have viruses in Virus Total: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9d34dce715ed46a77ee5e00d408e5d649cbce92c9cf4fe4da962a1397ebc70e4/detection

Comment: 2 out of 70+ is hardly proof that a real virus exists in that file. More likely the MD5 of that file simply matches something those 2 already saw before.  MD5 is not perfectly unique, [collisions do occur](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/).

Comment: im sorry for asking so many question but do you think this has a virus? it is a different executable more organized and easy to use injector from GuidedHacking as well. https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f4b498109edd2084639ad2bdc2085a30c13d3dc974832ab0956330650f33f7c3/detection

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is a false positive.

IDP Generic means: the detection was detected by a Identity Protection detection component and it is a generalized file that got detected.

Practically means that the program behaved in a way that is close to what a malware does. This could be a false positive.

Also, you could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894145/antivirus-detects-python-exe-as-idp-generic) which could be helpful.